# Compile boost with std=c++11 or other standards such ash c++14

Tags: c++, boost

I am using a Visual Studio GDB project and I have a problem including the the boost linux libraries in the linker inputs.

This are the error received:

> undefined reference to `std::__cxx11::basic_string, std::allocator >::_M_create(unsigned
>   long&, unsigned long)'

It seems that the library is not recognized as being compiled with -std=c++11

The commands used to compile the library are:

```
sudo ./boostrap.sh
sudo ./b2 toolset=gcc cxxflags="-std=c++11"
make
sudo make install
```

The compilation worked well.

I am using the boost 1.62.0 version and the gcc-5.4.0 version to compile the library. The library included in visual studio project as linker input is libboost_system.a

I think the error from visual studio is related to c++11 compilation.

Could you please tell me if the compilation procedure is ok?

If not, please tell which is the right procedure to compile the library for c++11?

Does the error mean something else?

Comment: This link should help: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-5.2.0/libstdc++/manual/manual/using_dual_abi.html Although I'm not sure it will work anyway. Why you compile boost with gcc and then try to link it to VS project???

Comment: "Visual Studio GDB project" and "boost linux libraries"?  Linux libraries aren't going to work on Windows.

Comment: Hello, The Visual Studio GDB project output is a linux application and a windows application which both start in the same time. 
The linux application is copied at build on a linux processor and runs from it.

Comment: My problem is that all the libraries that I use in my linker inputs are compiled with std=c++11 and also boost was compiled and it worked before. 
Now I am using a new libraries from boost:the system and filesystem library and I have error about c++11 compilation. 
I compiled again the boost using the commands which I wrote before but I still have the same error. 
Could you please tell me if I am using the right commands to compile the boost system/filesystem library? 
Do I missed something?

Answer (score 4):

Your steps to compile Boost with c++11 enabled are correct (although you don't need all the `sudo`). The problem then must be how you compile your own program: it should use **exactly** matching flags. Check that your program isn't e.g. using the compiler default, which could well be c++14 or c++03.

Comment: Is it possible to compile boost with say c++14 or c+17?  I saw the boost default is c++11

Comment: @KeminZhou Yes it's possible

Comment: I just compiled boost with C++17 and worked fine.